# Windows phone 8.1 WebView not displaying page correctly on using it's NavigateToString Method

Tags: html, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to display a web page in a webview in Windows Phone 8.1 (using lumia 520) using it's NavigateToString method.

I have created a class HtmlClass which contains the following [strings](http://pastebin.com/bQ5wvPeA).

1. post_head : header of page.
2. css_style : css code to be used.
3. post_title : html code to display title of post.
4. post_author : html code to display author of post.
5. post_content : html code to display content of post.
6. post_end : end of body.
7. script : jquery to be used.
8. end : marks end of html page.

I create a string "content"

```
string content = HtmlClass.post_head + HtmlClass.css_style + HtmlClass.post_title + title + HtmlClass.post_author + author + HtmlClass.post_content + div55.InnerHtml + HtmlClass.post_end + HtmlClass.script + HtmlClass.end;
```

div55.InnerHtml is the html code of the content ([sample content code](http://pastebin.com/fvwcN5t7)) to be displayed, extracted using HtmlAgilityPack.

and use

```
Post.NavigateToString(content);
```

to load the htmlpage in webview (Post is the name of webview).

The problem I face is that, the neither css nor jquery script in my page is executed. I tried executing a simple javascript (no jquery) funtion (change content of div on button click), but that too is not being executed.

But when I load the [test page](http://pastebin.com/6JqZfkF7) in webview using by using it's Navigate(Uri url) method, with url set to address which I used to access the page through apache and it displays it correctly.

Displayed correctly in internet explorer/and in webview on using Navigate(Uri url)

[image: Displayed correctly in internet explorer]

Not correctly displayed in webview

[image: Not correctly displayed in webview]

Comment: Looks like your css is not loaded. Please provide details of the content you are loading. (There are a lot of limitations when using navigate to string.)

Comment: @KaiBrummund Css is lading fine, but the script is not being executed. I even tried loading page from inside app package but it had the same problem.

Comment: Again: Need Content Details for further help. Is the script a local file? Have you tried using NavigateToLocalStream?

Comment: You are loading jQuery as an external resource... I don't thin that works with NavigateToString. (Not sure though.)

Answer (score 1):

When using the `WebView` or `WebBrowser` control on Windows Phone, make sure the HTML you're trying to view is a [valid HTML document](http://validator.w3.org/) with a valid DOCTYPE, etc.

With Windows Phone 8.1 the `WebView` control needs `@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }` to format content properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { font-size: 16px; }
        @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- INSERT YOUR HTML HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: neither css nor jquery is not being executed. Please read the updated question.

Comment: @user3263192 JS execution is actually a different issue - can you post the HTML source you're trying to render?